# Precipitation with NaI

Tags: homework, experimental-chemistry, aqueous-solution, coordination-compounds

I dissolved $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4](NO3)2}$ in water then I added small amount of $\ce{NaI}$ ($1~\mathrm{M}$) to it. Precipitation occurred. I want to know what happened?

Comment: Hi and welcome to chemistry.stackexchange.com. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site. I improved the formatting of your post by using MathJax; you can learn more about that in the [help], [this meta-post](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/7475) or [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/444/7475).

Comment: You precipitated platinum(II) iodide.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you see any gas evolution?

Comment: I thought it is PtI2. but when I took xrd for  the precipitation, I saw too many peaks which I got confused on assigning  the peaks to PtI2.

Comment: I didn't see any gas evolution.

Answer (score 1):

The original solution contains the square planar $\ce{Pt(II)}$ complex ion $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4]^2+}$. When sodium iodide is added to the solution, one or more $\ce{NH3}$ molecules are replaced by $\ce{I-}$ ions in a ligand exchange reaction. In particular, replacing two $\ce{NH3}$ molecules with $\ce{I-}$ ions yields the neutral complex $\ce{[PtI2(NH3)2]}$, which is poorly soluble in water, and therefore a precipitate is formed.

Remarkably, two isomers of square planar $\ce{[PtI2(NH3)2]}$ exist: $\ce{$cis${-}[PtI2(NH3)2]}$ and $\ce{$trans${-}[PtI2(NH3)2]}$.
When starting from $\ce{[Pt(NH3)4]^2+}$, the first $\ce{I-}$ can replace any of the four equivalent $\ce{NH3}$ ligands. Because of the larger **trans effect** of $\ce{I-}$ compared to $\ce{NH3}$, the second $\ce{NH3}$ is preferably replaced *trans* to the first $\ce{I-}$ ligand and therefore the *trans* product $\ce{$trans${-}[PtI2(NH3)2]}$ is obtained.
(Note that, if one starts from $\ce{[PtI4]^2- }$ and replaces two $\ce{I-}$ ligands with $\ce{NH3}$, the *cis* product $\ce{$cis${-}[PtI2(NH3)2]}$ is obtained instead.)

Comment: But when I solved pt(NH3)4(OH)2 with NaI in water, precipitation didn't happen. Why it didn't give precipitation?
Thanks